# Timer with limited number of flashes

Tags: c#, winforms

I need the timer to blink 8 times when starting the form: "Press the OK button" and stopped blinking.
Searched the Internet, but did not find. I tried to write a cycle, but still do not understand how to write it. Can you write a timer and explain how it works?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp7
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer1.Start();
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void button1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            int w = (int)this.button1.Size.Width;
            int h = (int)this.button1.Size.Height;
            Random r = new Random();
            button1.Left = r.Next(0, this.Size.Width - button1.Width);
            button1.Top = r.Next(0, this.Size.Height - button1.Height);
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(w - 3, h - 3);
            if (button1.Focused)
            {
                this.Text = "Мимо";

            }
            else
            {
                this.Text = "Нажміть на кнопку ОК!!!";
            }
        }
        private int time;

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         
            this.Text = time.ToString("click OK"); //timer
          
            
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you means "blink"

Comment: I mean, when you run the form, the message appears for 1 second and disappears. And so 8 times. After 8 times, the message remains in form.

Comment: ok, so you a want a message apears for 1 sec and after this the popup desapear and apears again after 8 sec?

Comment: I mean that after starting the form, the name of the form should flash 8 times with the text "Click" OK !!!". After 8 flashes, the inscription should remain on the form

Comment: Your Timer needs an Interval (of 1000) and the time variable needs to be counted up and tested. For 8 on and 8 off intervals you need to count to 16 then stop. To decide if you are in an on or off period test time%2==0..